# Check uniqueness of ID inside CKEditor content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

**Task:** When adding anchor with id in CKEditor, I want to check id's uniqueness for entire page.

**Problem:** If I access directly CKEditor content it may have [fakeobjects](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/fakeobjects) for elements with same id.

If i get CKEditor content with getData() which will return plain html and not DOM.

**Question:** What is complete and easiest way to check uniqueness of element's id in CKEditor

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way seems to be utilizing CKEditor API and search editor content for:

1. Regular elements with the same id.
2. Fake elements holding regular elements with the same id.

Finding regular elements with the same id is easy with [`CKEDITOR.dom.element.find` method](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element-method-find):

```
var sameIdNode = [],
    regularNodes = editor.editable().find( '[id=' + id + ']' ).toArray();

CKEDITOR.tools.array.forEach( regularNodes, function( node ) {
    // Check if it is not a fake element.
    if ( !node.getAttribute( 'data-cke-realelement' ) ) {
        sameIdNodes.push( node )
    }
} );
```

Similar with fake element, however their real content needs to be decode to be searched:

```
var fakeNodes = editor.editable().find( '[data-cke-realelement]' ).toArray(),
    realElement = null,
    sameIdNodes = [];

// Check fake elements.
CKEDITOR.tools.array.forEach( fakeNodes, function( node ) {
    // Decode realelement and convert into CKEDITOR.dom.element so `find` could be used. Wrap in a `div` so find will also check outermost element.
    realElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<div>' + decodeURIComponent( node.getAttribute( 'data-cke-realelement' ) ) + '</div>' );
    sameIdNodes = sameIdNodes.concat( realElement.find( '[id=' + id + ']' ).toArray() );
} );
```

For the working, simple example check [this codepen](https://codepen.io/f1ames/pen/YEVgRe?editors=1010).